# How to keep running my scheduler regardless of my server

Tags: java, scheduler

In my project i have a scheduler running, when I deploy my project on live server i have to stop the server deploy my changes and then to restart it.
and in this whole process my scheduler reset. I want to run my scheduler in any case .
Is this possible ??
If yes. How ?

Comment: You would need to provide some more information. What frameworks are you using?

Comment: I am using spring MVC and Quartz scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what type of server environment in question. But I assume yours might be some application server or web server. In that case Scheduled jobs can be creating batch job and schedule it through cron   Tab on Linux/Unix (assuming your application is running on Unix/Linux box).

Answer (score 1):

use a cron scheduler like quartz that triggers independent of the process runtime (e.g. uses default cron trigger syntax instead of being activated every X seconds). That way the invocation interval will remain constant even when restarting the process.

that will also give you features like persistent cron jobs. Spring should support this out of the box by using org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean's dataSource properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on a Windows-based server, then you could use the [Revalee](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com) open source project to solve this issue. Revalee, which runs as a Windows Service, stores all scheduled tasks in a persistent data store (specifically, the Extensible Storage Engine (ESE) [aka. JET Blue]), so that you will not lose state even if your entire server needs to be rebooted. When your task is due, Revalee calls your application back in order to trigger whatever task you needed to run.